# What's wrong with min-height?

Tags: html, css

Simple fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yy1poyh5/).

Why doesn't `min-height` work the way you might think, and indeed not according to the documentation either?

Why doesn't this div fill up with a 100px by 100px box?

HTML:

```
<div class="div1"><div class="div2"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

Why does `height` work and not `min-height`?

Comment: You could add `min-height: inherit`.. http://jsfiddle.net/k8cobzob/

Comment: div2 is indeed the problem. 100% of what...

Comment: @Mikey Of the containing div as usual. Why does the question "100% of what?" arise just because I'm using `min-height`, and not simply `height`, that's what I'm wondering.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson You have your answer below, but min-height is not specific enough. When you inspect your element(s) especially the second div you will see it has a height of 0;

Comment: @LindonJohnson If you replace `min-height` by `auto` it will give you the same problems even with content in you div.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson - the reason why the accepted answer works, whereas your posted example doesn't, has to do with browsers' [render tree construction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en). Setting a not-Normal `position` on both elements delegates the responsibility from `layout` to `paint` as the browser parses the document. A great example of this in action is if you set `.div2`  position to `absolute` and do not set the position of `div1` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy1poyh5/13/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is `%` on `height` for div2 not the min-height.

For Percentage Height:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto.

<sub>**[MDN Height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)**</sub>

So you need a fixed value to refer from `div1` or you can make `div2` absolute:

```css
.div1 {
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position:relative;
}

.div2 {
    position:Absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"><div class="div2"></div></div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but just one thing I was going to stress from the spec is `(i.e., it depends on content height)`.  Though with `min-height` the height isn't **entirely** dependent on the content height, it still is somewhat dependent--when the content extends beyond the min-height.

Comment: This is what I don't really get. The containing block is the div1, which is explicitly set to (a minimum of) 100px. So div2 should fill with *at least* a 100 by 100 px box. If the absolute positioning is the problem, then why does it work when I set div1 to `height: 100px`?

Comment: @LyndonJohnson because min-height *isn't* explicitly setting the height of the element, it's being conditionally set. Even if you just add `height:1px;` to the css for div1, it will work as you intend, because and explicit value has now been set, and _then_ overridden by the min-height conditional.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson read carefully the extract from MDN you need an explicit value to refer the `%`unit `min-height` isn't a  value specified explicitly.

Comment: To be fair, that article goes on to say "The min-height and max-height properties override height", which is... misleading to say the least. I see why there's a "needs technical review" notice on the article.

Comment: I see. Still a bit weird to me, as the height of div1 works and everything, but all right. By the way, "i.e." doesn't stand for "in example", it stands for "id est" which means "it is" and is not an actual example. ;)